# Special characters are not proper after sqooping data into Hive from teradata

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to sqoop the teradata table into Hive using below "sqoop-import" command.

```
sqoop tdimport
    -Dtdch.output.hdfs.avro.schema.file=/tmp/data/country.avsc --connect jdbc:teradata://tdserver/database=SALES  --username tduser
    --password tdpw --as-avrodatafile --target-dir  /tmp/data/country_avro --table COUNTRY
    --split-by SALESCOUNTRYCODE  --num-mappers 1
```

The teradata table contains special characters in some columns.After sqooping into Hive, the special characters are not coming proper.

Is there any way to enable the special characters while firing the sqoop import command?

Do we need to use UTF-8, to resolve this issue ?

Can anyone please suggest me regarding this issue ...

Comment: You want to import special character too or you want to drop the special character while importing ?

Comment: _"special character"_ is quite vague -- what is the **charset** used by your Teradata system? Did you try to set `CHARSET=UTF8` in your JDBC URL, so that Teradata converts automatically all text to UTF-8 encoding as expected by Hive?

Comment: I want to import special characters also while importing into Hive

Comment: UTF-8 is default implementation in Sqoop and junk character will affect the data quality in hive. for example `^M` will get replace by `\n` and hence you will get count mismatch issue.

Comment: I suggests to review your requirement and clean the junk character during import.

Comment: I'm able to import special characters properly into Hive by using CHARSET=UTF8 in your JDBC URL. It worked out for me. Thanks a lot for ur help @Samson Scharfrichter

Comment: Fine, so please update your question and explain (briefly) what was the root cause and how you fixed it.

Comment: I had solved my issue by using the below command by adding CHARSET =UTF8 to the JDBC connection string:

sqoop tdimport
        -Dtdch.output.hdfs.avro.schema.file=/tmp/data/country.avsc --connect jdbc:teradata://tdserver/database=SALES,CHARSET=UTF8  --username tduser
        --password tdpw --as-avrodatafile --target-dir  /tmp/data/country_avro --table COUNTRY
        --split-by SALESCOUNTRYCODE  --num-mappers 1